# Form Post Method is not working while using AMP Plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using AMP Plugin in my site.

I have created custom template for another page. And in that we have a Form to submit data. But When I click on submit button no action is performed.I am getting a blank value in the mail.I get the following error in the console-

`Error: Only XHR based (via action-xhr attribute) submissions are support for POST requests`.

I searched on google and added action-xhr instead of form action. But it didn't help either

find the below code,

```html
<?php
if(isset( $_POST['hosting']))
    $hosting = $_POST['hosting'];
if(isset( $_POST['email']))
    $email = $_POST['email'];

$content="\n Hosting : $hosting \n
  Email: $email \n
  
$recipients = array(
                "tejas@gmail.com"
            );
$to = implode(',', $recipients);
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $content, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

?>

<form name="myForm" id="myform" method="POST" onsubmit="alert('Message has been sent');">
    <input required data-map-to="hosting_id_autocomplete" name="hosting_id" value="" aria-required="true" type="hidden" required/>
    <input placeholder="Email" name="email" class="large_input formemail " required aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" type="email" required/>
    --
    <input type="submit" class="button arial grey orange" name="submit" >
    </form>
```

Can you tell me what is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: provide a code snippet for people to find the reason for your error

Comment: there is no action-xhr attribute in your form code, please check https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/ example for more..